# Formatting plain text in C#

Tags: c#, text, formatting

I am trying to format text that will be sent in an email to a user. Currently, I am simply printing to the console to make sure the formatting is correct. I used all the escape characters I found while doing my research such as `/r/n` and `/t` but it's not working. The escape characters just show up in the text. For example, if I were to put

```
string someStringVar = boo;
"Hello World! /r/n" + someStringVar + "/t Goodbye!", I would expect the text to look like:
```

Hello World!

boo -tab- Goodbye!

instead, it looks like this:

> Hello World! /r/nboo/t Goodbye!

Why???? I'm sure it's some stupid mistake, but I am too frustrated to figure it out. Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use **back**slashes:

```
"Hello World! \r\n" + someStringVar + "\t Goodbye!"
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `/t` try `\t` you are using wrong **slash**

Same thing is wrong with rest of the escape sequences

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing emails, you might also want to look at Papercut and nDumbster, both of these are available on www.codeplex.com